# Combinatorial argument for words of length $n$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

A **word** of length $n$ is a sequence of letters obtained from some set.

For this problem, consider a word of length $n$ whose letters come from the set $\{0,1\}$. Let $w(n)$ denote the number of such words without adjacent zeros. For example $w(2)=3$ since the only valid words are $01, 10, 11$.

I have found that for $n\geq 3$
$$w(n)=w(n-1)+w(n-2)$$
where $w(1)=2$ and $w(2)=3$.

I would like to prove the recurrence relation combinatorially, but I have no idea how to begin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: combinatorial identities are often proved with bijections. Write $W_n$ for the set of words you describe of length $n$, so that $w(n) = |W_n|$. Can you give a bijection $W_n \to W_{n-1} \cup W_{n-2}$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Any such word ends with a $1$ or a $10$.

Comment: This was exactly the hint I needed.